# What is the correct?

Tags: meaning, grammar, meaning-in-context

What is the right choice
 “I started playing piano when i was six “
Or “I was starting playing piano when i was six “ , and why?

Comment: Your first example is correct. The succession of gerund-participles in the second is excluded by what is called the 'double-_ing_ constraint'. The constraint usually applies with aspectual verbs such as "begin", "cease", "start", "stop" and a few others.

Comment: Idiomatically, we tend to avoid two consecutive ***-ing*** forms, so the second version is probably unlikely / awkward in *any* context. But even *I **was starting to play** [the] piano when i was six* is unlikely, because ***when*** after the continuous verb form *(**starting**)* normally implies *at the same time* (it's nearly always followed by an event / action identifying a ***specific*** point in time, not just a "time-span", such as an age in years). Thus *I was starting to do X **when Y happened*** is quite natural, but normally ***...when I was a child*** wouldn't be.

Answer (score -1):

I used to play piano when I was six. Maybe it isn't corrent